# SQL insert to table variable from SELECT result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, insert

Just for Information if you would like to read:
(I'm working on a SQL database update program. I have an (old) ICD Code table and I want to insert new records (~90k records) into the old one. If there are no existed ICD code, then insert, if yes update. The problem is the data to be inserted is from a table call IcdImportData (import from .csv file) and I need to create a **variable table** that contains the compare value of the old table and new ImportData table.)

**What I'm asking about:**
I want to insert values to a variable table, from a Select statement that returns many records. How can I do that?

This is the code:

```
SELECT IcdCodeID FROM
(
    SELECT IcdCodeID FROM IcdImportData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IcdCodeValue FROM IcdCode
) tmp
GROUP BY IcdCodeID
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

and I want to insert the result to this variable table:

```
DECLARE @temp table (IcdCodeValue NCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT
(
*The code above*
)
```

The Error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: See `INSERT` syntax for your rdbms

Comment: Please show the actual insert statement that is failing.  Also, what database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works , You have to remove one extra `select`

```
DECLARE @temp table (IcdCodeValue NCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT IcdCodeID FROM
(
        SELECT IcdCodeID FROM IcdImportData
        UNION ALL
        SELECT IcdCodeValue FROM IcdCode
) tmp
GROUP BY IcdCodeID
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

or do it this way

```
DECLARE @temp table (IcdCodeValue NCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT IcdCodeID FROM
(
        SELECT IcdCodeID FROM IcdImportData
        UNION ALL
        SELECT IcdCodeValue FROM IcdCode
) tmp
GROUP BY IcdCodeID
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2) t
```